# How can I use v-html to pass a text with props and images?

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to pass different texts to a component list. Each text has a different title and also different content, but the same style. To do this I'm using another component that takes a v-html. I need to pass an image inside this v-html and also several props. However, the image does not appear and the props do not work. How can I solve this? I don't want to change my "message" component because I'm using it in other areas of my website and it's working fine.

App.Vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="raleway">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
    <section class="container grid">
      <div
         v-for="metadata in this.metadatas"
        :key="metadata.id"
        class="steps-wrapper text"
      >
      <Team :metadata="metadata"/>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Team from "./components/Team.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Team,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      metadatas: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Title1",
          country: "Brazil"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Title2",
          country: "England"
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Component (Team):

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="raleway">
    <section>
      <div class="steps-wrapper text">
        <Step/>
        <div class="image-cropper">
          <img src="../assets/me.jpg" alt="" class="profile-pic">
        </div>
        <Message v-html="content" />
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Step from "./CreationView";
import Message from "./Message";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Step,
    Message
  },
  props: {
    metadata: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      content:
        "<h2>{{metadata.name}}</h2>\
         <h2><img src='../assets/discord.svg' alt=''>Head</h2>\
          <p id='country'> {{metadata.country}} </p>\
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Component (Message):

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <section>
      </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Message',
}
</script>
```

Comment: In your ‘app.vue’ file, you are passing ‘metadata’ to the Teams component while you have defined ‘metadatas’. Notice the extra ‘s’. Also in your message component, it does not accept any props, so how are you passing any props if it does not accept any?

Comment: Well it works. I don't know if it's the correct way to do it, but it worked for all props that I tried to pass